# How to switch Database connection while staging to production hot swap

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I have a CI/CD pipeline where on VSTS with following considerations:

- Web App is an ASP.NET Core project and is hosted on Azure with an "staging" slot
- Staging will be connected to a non-production/ synced database for testing
- Connection string in Staging will be pointing to Staging DB
- Connection string in Production will be pointing to Production DB
- While doing hot swap, the connection string should remain same of the staging as it will become the new production.

The problem I'm facing is while doing the hot swap the connection string wil be picked from the Application Settings from Production Web App which will be pointig to Production DB.

The connection string can be changed in Application Settings on Azure Web App on Azure portal but it requires a Restart - which will negate the value of hot swap!

Any hints on how to replace the connection string while doing hot swap.

PS: We have the connection strings mentioned in Azure Portal's Web App > Application Settings

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:**

Here's a depiction of my consideration:

[image]

Comment: See if this helps: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/09/04/database-connection-string-when-swapping-between-app-servers-slots/.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have a staging environment which is on a deployment slot of your production environment, right? If so: please don't. As deployment slots point towards the same app service plan, heavy load (or a bad version) on staging can mess with your production environment. Have an _actual_, separate staging environment to do all testing and use deployment slots as nothing else than having a new deployment ready to be able to swap. As for your question: see @GauravMantri 's comment :)

Comment: thanks for the hints @rickvdbosch, I'm aware of the risks. As the application is a bit tiny - I wanted to save bucks here.

Comment: thanks @GauravMantri sir for pointer, let me try that. I've added a depiction of the problem statement. I know it's not advisable but just to avoid having another environment.

Comment: When do you want to swap slot? During build/release? What's the detail workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you are using the same app service plan one environment can interfere in the other one. Having this in mind, and assuming you are using release manager, you could:

1 - Create two separated environments in a release, one for staging and one for production

2 - Create a variable with the same name as your connection string name in your web.config, one scoped for staging environment and the other for production.

3 - Add a Deploy Azure App Service task to each environment.

Then you could use the File transformation and substitution options and mark to make the transformation. It will use the name of your variable and replace it in your config file. Take a look at XML Transformation and JSON transformation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=vsts.

[image]

And you can add the Application and configuration settings.

[image]